# Simple JavaScript Split Function

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I'm questioning why I got the following output from this code:

```
'Willie'.split(/[i-l]{1}/); // [ 'W', '', '', '', 'e' ]
```

I was expecting to get `['W', 'e']`. I'm not sure why it's inserting holes in the array.

Answer (score 4):

You are splitting on single letter, so each `illi` is considered as a separator, and the string splits as follows:

```
 w   i   l   l   i   e
# w   ""  ""  ""  e
# if there's no content between separators, an empty string is in place

# or what would you get with a csv string w,,,,e split on comma ?
```

Try using a greedy quantifier `+` which will match the pattern as long as it can, so `illi` is considered as one separator:

```js
console.log('Willie'.split(/[i-l]+/));
```

Answer (score 3):

You are splitting the `Willie` string by `i`, `j`, `k`, `l` characters. If `il` substring appears, and both `i` and `l` are separators, between those letters there is an empty string - which is counted in the result.

Let's analyze whole string:

```
'W', '', 'i', '', 'l', '', 'l', '', 'i', '', 'e'
```

Then split it by `i` and `l`:

```
('W', ''), /i separator/, '', /l separator/, '', /l separator/, '', /i separator/, ('', 'e')
```

so after concatenation groups we get:

```
'W', '', '', '', 'e'
```

Comment: In your second code example, you have 5 `''` instances. I expect all 5 of those empty strings `''` to appear in the array now. Could you explain why the first and last set of `''` were bound to the letters `'W'` and `'e'` respectively?

Comment: Because `('W' '')` and `('', 'e')` are before/after separators so they are counted as a one substrings.

Comment: I feel like there's some basic concepts about these `''` substrings that I'm not understanding. Could you link to any links or documents?